# dynamic load and rotate image jquery

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, rotation

I am loading image dynamically and have image array ,
so I want to load one image then store it in array.so My array length would be 1.then I want to rotate image which is already stored in array then store it in array..
so now image array length will be 2.
first image will be dynamically loaded and 2nd is rotated.

```
var timg = new Image();
timg.onload=function(){

};  
images.push(timg);
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotated? Using css rules?

Comment: use transform:rotate(10deg) to rotate image

Comment: don't want to rotate with css,,I want to  actullay roatete image then store it in array.